# .dot document is being downloaded as .doc in iis

Tags: iis, ms-word

I have a web app running on IIS 7 and I have a hyperlink to a .dot (Microsoft Word template) document (mytemplate.dot).

However, when the users (or myself) try downloading it, they got the file as a Word normal document (mytemplate.doc).

I've tried to modified the MIME type of .dot file from application/msword to application/dot; and also have tried removing the MIME type completely, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When does it become a .doc file, when it's downloaded (transformed in the download process) or is it just prompting you to save it as a .doc file (which is standard behavior for templates).

Comment: The prompt is asking me to save it like a .doc. I didn't know that was the standard behavior, and the final users don't expect a .doc document to be saved

Comment: Does the prompt let you change it back to .dot?  If so, that's how you'll have to do it.  Is this in IE by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it happens on IE but also on FF and Chrome. I don't mind changing the extension, but the users says that is not the expected behavior (yucks). Many thanks Mike.

Comment: Funny how much effort goes into managing users expectations and misunderstandings of technology, eh?